# GlassFish Starting Up Java SE Client - No Initial Context Exception

Tags: java, client, glassfish

I have developed a java se client that calls some session beans on a glassfish server v3. I connect to the bean remote interface like this.

```
context = new InitialContext();
em = (ICrudService) context.lookup("java:global/BackITServer/CrudServiceImpl");
```

This works fine from inside eclipse (gf-client on build path). When I export my project as a runnable jar and call it on the console with

```
java -jar BackItClient.jar
```

I get a NoInitialContextException.

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name 
in enviroment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file
```

MMMM. I would very much appreciate some help.

Thank You

Greetings Marcel

PS: Do I really have to pack all the jars which gf-client is referencing into my jar?

Answer (score 0):

OK

It works when I do the following in the modules directory of glassfish:

```
java -cp gf-client.jar;c:/users/marcel/desktop/backITClient.jar gui.MainController
```

BUT

If I move up one directory and do the following:

```
java -cp /modules/gf-client.jar;c:/users/marcel/desktop/backITClient.jar gui.MainController
```

I get the NoInitialContextException again

Moreover all the relative paths in the client don't work anymore (i18n xml files/ pictures) since it looks it up in the modules directory. ???

I know one should "do learn the trade first, then download an IDE", nevertheless I hope someone could give me a hint.

Thanks

Marcel

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved It. I had to reinstall glassfish. It was in the program files directory, a folder java doesn't like.

```
java -cp c:/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/gf-client.jar;backITClient.jar gui.MainController
```

Greetings

Marcel